# Taking the covariant derivative of a metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In my notes we are taking the derivative of a metric tensor and it shows the following

[image: shown here]

Im wondering why the christoffel symbol when considering cartesian coordinates is zero

Comment: Christoffels tell you how the coordinate basis vector directions $\hat e$ change from place to place, no? So consider how that applies to a Cartesian system.

Comment: So I know that in a curved space the basis vector changes but of the fact that it is curved but in an xyz plane it wouldn't change? like if I had a vector that pointed up on an x axis if I moved it to the right it would still point up. so since there is no change from place to place it is zero, is this a correct way of thinking about it?

Comment: That's correct, and in particular the directions $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ and $\hat z$ themselves do not change from place to place.  Contrast that with the directions $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ and $\hat \phi$ in a spherical coordinate system

Comment: this makes so much sense thank you!